# ec2 connect refused to connect to an instance, but nacl and sec group have the inbound rules, reason?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-vpc, aws-security-group, network-security-groups

i created my own sec group with the rules that allow http , https, ssh over 22, icmp. But somehow 'ping public_ip' from my bash not working.

I know the problem should be either in nacl or sec group.

nacl inbound rules(std, i did not change):

- 100 - source: 0.0.0.0/0 - All traffic allow
- '*' 0.0.0.0/0 - All traffic deny

sec group:

```
–
sgr-04d94a952ec860ae0   IPv4    All ICMP - IPv4 ICMP    All 0.0.0.0/0   –

–
sgr-024a8c2d7b5d0655b   IPv4    HTTP    TCP 80  0.0.0.0/0   –

–
sgr-0850c40886cae6d8e   –   All traffic All All sg-0dfbcaaeddb9d6290 / default  –

–
sgr-0d8d763897c3887c1   IPv6    HTTPS   TCP 443 ::/0    –

–
sgr-03cd30e21cf350d33   IPv4    SSH TCP 22  0.0.0.0/0   –

–
sgr-00d6311720aeb475f   IPv6    HTTP    TCP 80  ::/0    –

–
sgr-09439547961e2f68f   IPv4    HTTPS   TCP 443
```

checking with ping does not work.... :
ping 3.209.9.15  -> 'request time out'

explicit ssh does not work!

```
ssh -i minikube_keypair.pem ubuntu@ec2-3-209-9-15.compute-1.amazonaws.com
ssh: connect to host ec2-3-209-9-15.compute-1.amazonaws.com port 22: Connection refused
```

Comment: Ping is only useful for testing whether Ping works. Rather than using Ping, you should concentrate on getting your _actual_ service to work (eg SSH or HTTP). The fact that you are receiving a `Connection refused` indicates that ssh managed to successfully connect to the instance, but the connection was refused. Add `-vvv` to your command (eg `ssh -vvv ...`) to obtain debug information. It is likely that the keypair is being refused.

Comment: Is the EC2 deployed in public subnet as just having public ip doesnt guarantee the route exists for it.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein here s what i got:


debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts2' -> '/c/Users/erjan/.ssh/known_hosts2'
debug2: resolving "ec2-52-7-61-134.compute-1.amazonaws.com" port 22
debug2: ssh_connect_direct
debug1: Connecting to ec2-52-7-61-134.compute-1.amazonaws.com [52.7.61.134] port 22.
debug1: connect to address 52.7.61.134 port 22: Connection refused
ssh: connect to host ec2-52-7-61-134.compute-1.amazonaws.com port 22: Connection refused

Answer (score 1):

the problem was i deleted internet gateway.

do 2 things:

- check if you have internet gateway (if not - create it & attach to vpc)
- check if route attached to your subnet has a rule that uses internet gateway.

the rule in the route table can look like this:

```
0.0.0.0/0   igw-067c712c04da342ee    Active No
```